# fix at bottom of page

Tags: css, printing

I'm writing a print stylesheet for my pages. each page has a footer. and the footer should stay at bottom of the printed page.. if it has `30pt` white spaces before. (if there is `30pt` spaces between main content and footer, footer should fix at bottom; else, it should go to next page)

because I'm using print stylesheet, I think I can't use `JavaScript` to check and fix it. (so please suggest a style solution)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JS, just CSS - I use the sticky footer solution here: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com

Comment: No actually, it needs a lot of CSS.. I go with `position:absolute` and `bottom:0`

Comment: Your solution does not take into account what happens when the page is long, nor does it specify padding between it and the rest of the page.  Depends what you're happy with, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

you doesn't specify your code, anywhere i think by using position property you can fix your footer.

```
   .footer{

    position: fixed;}
```